# Scikit-learn Multicore: "AttributeError: StdIn instance has no attribute 'close'"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm to run a RandomForestRegressor from Scikit-learn.  This works fine when executing the whole script:

```
clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs = 4, verbose=1, oob_score=True)
clf = clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

When I try to run the line from the console I get this error repeatedly:

```
AttributeError: StdIn instance has no attribute 'close'
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    sys.stdin.close()
```

If I change the `n_jobs` parameter to `n_jobs=1` I don't get an error, but it can't take advantage of multithreading.

I'm assuming this has to do with the fact that the PyCharm console is redirecting stdin, but I'm not sure how to get it to work.  Any thoughts are appreciated - thanks!

Comment: For multithreading use `n_jobs = -1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coming a little late to the party, but I encountered the same problem myself just now.

The workaround, suggested in the other answer, is to avoid the interactive interpreter of PyCharm. This, of course, works but does not satisfy me since I like to use the interactive interpreter very much.

I found a different workaround that solves the problem *and* allows the usage of the interactive interpreter. Before **each** creation of a new process via `multiprocessing.Process()`, the following code snippet has to be applied:

```
if not hasattr(sys.stdin, 'close'):
    def dummy_close():
        pass
    sys.stdin.close = dummy_close
```

Now, `multiprocessing` can call `close()` on `sys.stdin` just fine, and everything works smoothly.

Please note that it is not sufficient to attach the dummy `close()` once during a start-up phase. I found that it is necessary to do it before each call to `multiprocessing.Process()`; I didn't try it with process pools, though.

Comment: it might a very dangerous thing to do...but I solve for multiprocessing.Pool and all the other just editing "process.py" and adding these lines where the error is risen. (for me was "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py:249")

Answer (score 0):

As the PyCharm is primarily an **IDE**, it supports rapid source-code text typing, self-introspections, prototyping and debugging efforts.

as a rule of thumb, validate your { hardware | VM } capability to work parallel:

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

## Parallel Multiprocessing while inside PyCharm IDE

Do not waste CPU-time to run an already fine-tuned code inside any IDE, be it on an IDE-integrated-python-engine or on an IDE-remote-python-engine ( a known the case for PyScripter IDE et al ).

A well-done python code will run safe and faster in a plain command-line launched like **`C:\Python2.7\python.exe aRandomForestJOB.py`**

If the PyCharm console remains to be blocking your path to multiprocessing,
try to run the same code in a standalone python interpreter to re-produce the issue and post the post-mortem messages, should your code crashes there.

## PyCharm `sys.stdin.close()` error Workaround

Nathan Lemoine reports:

'''
PyCharm 3 includes a **local terminal**. I open python in that terminal and it runs fine, which allows me to debug and work interactively. This makes me thing it’s a problem specific to the way PyCharm runs its *interactive interpreter*. But since the workaround is so easy, it’s not really an issue.
'''

Comment: When I run the `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` command I get 8.  I only thought my MacBook had a quad-core, which is a little confusing.

Comment: The issue that I'm posting about above is that I get an error only when using PyCharm's console.  When I "Run" the full script from PyCharm the multithreading seems to work fine.  So one answer could be "don't use PyCharm's console", but that would be a shame.  It's helpful for many things.  

I think the issue is that when running in console-mode some things gets redirected to stdin, which has no close method (since it's stdin after all).

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it simpler for python new guys like my, I sum up a solution from previous answers and comments. Open `process.py`, on my Linux system it was done by:

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py
```

Before changing it, I would back it up for easy restore if something goes wrong,
then find in `process.py` "bootstrap" and change it to begin like this:

```
def _bootstrap(self):
    from . import util
    global _current_process
    if not hasattr(sys.stdin, 'close'):
        def dummy_close():
            pass
        sys.stdin.close = dummy_close
    try:
```